# How to Declare a variable which increment variable after one day is passed in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I need to increament variable on the basis of number of day. For example

just Like $day = "120";
then tomorrow that $day variable is 121.

Comment: It's not possible with variable. You need to store it in database.

Comment: Have you attempted anything? I see you understand you cannot do this purely with PHP and you'll need javascript. But stack isn't here as a free coding service. We need a bit of information on what you've tried already.

Comment: You could use `date('z')` to retrieve the day of the year and use that; but that would mean that the value starts again from 0 on 1/01. Other option is to save the variable somewhere (for example - to a file) and increment it when the date of saving changes

Comment: Since PHP is typically stateless, this in itself makes little sense. Describe what you're trying to achieve with this, don't ask about details of a wrongheaded solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you know what the starting count is, and at what time you began counting. You won't need a database if you have those two pieces of information up front.

```
<?php
$start_count = 120; // Original starting position (counter).
$start_time  = strtotime('2017-11-08 00:00:00'); // Original start time.
                                                 // Format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

$now  = time(); // Time now, in seconds.
$diff = $now - $start_time; // Difference, in seconds.

$days          = floor($diff / 86400); // Divide by seconds in one day.
$current_count = $start_count + $days; // Start count + days since start time.
```

Comment: Thank You For Help. Its work properly